# There is an error in XML document (1, 504)

Tags: c#, web-services, service, jax-rpc

i use this wsdl service http://ws.adpdigital.com/services/MessagingService?wsdl in c#

when i run it in windows application it's ok but when i run it as a windows service that give me an error

exception.message :

> There is an error in XML document (1, 504).
>
> exception.trace :
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   SendSmsToMagfa.com.adpdigital.ws.JaxRpcMessagingServiceService.report(String
>   userName, String password, String shortNumber, String fromClientId,
>   String clientId, String fromId, String id, Int32 maxSize)    at
>   SendSmsToMagfa.SendSms.Send(String[] message, String[] mobile,
>   String[] id, String[] port)    at
>   SendSmsService.SendSmsService.ServiceSmsMethod(Object sender,
>   ElapsedEventArgs e)

i checked it in .net 2 and 3 and 3.5 and 4 but all of them have error

what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you offer a code example?

Comment: sample of code is this but it's work here and when i use it as windows service it has error....com.adpdigital.ws.JaxRpcMessagingServiceService s = new com.adpdigital.ws.JaxRpcMessagingServiceService();
            com.adpdigital.ws.SendResult sr = s.send("********", "******", "0000000", new string[] { "0000000000" }, null, null, new string[] { "99" }, 1, 2, true, DateTime.Now, "test");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.status);
            if (sr.status == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.id[0]);
            }

Comment: Maybe someone parameter with null value is a problem, use a Fiddler tool to inspect a traffic.

Comment: oh i forget to say a notice that when that error occur my method is run but when that method want to get result throw error .

Comment: Do you know a language used for this SOAP service?